# Dupe of question originally on Sound Design

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

[Free music for commercial use project?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/24297/free-music-for-commercial-use-project)
is marked as a dupe of https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/23059/where-to-find-free-music
but the latter appears on Sound Design. Should there be a Video Production version of this question as the original?

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case we are probably ok with relaying it since there are already posts marked as dupe of it.  This is an odd artifact of the fact that half of sound design and video production were once the same site but then the primarily sound related questions were migrated off to Sound Design.  If it's purely finding sound, it probably is only borderline on-topic anyway vs being a Sound Design question which is why the predecessor was migrated.

Comment: Actually, when I think about it, it's a shopping cart type question and is going to attract link-only answers so it's probably a fairly low-quality question anyway.

Comment: Also a good point